# Select all rows that share common id

Tags: sql, database

Hi need help with this one

SO i have the following table example:

```
id  meta_key    data_id     meta_value

1   meta_1          1       example@email.com
2   meta_2          1            on
3   meta_id         1          11111
4   meta_1          2       example2@email.com
5   meta_2          2            on
6   meta_id         2          22222
7   meta_1          3       example3@gmail.com
8   meta_2          3            on
9   meta_id         3          111111
```

How can i select only the email that share 11111 meta_value

So in the case i should get rows that has example@email.com and example3@gmail.com as both share 11111 meta_id value

Help much appreciated and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery for this.

```sql
SELECT meta_value 
FROM   table_name t 
WHERE  t.meta_key= 'meta_1' 
       AND t.data_id IN (SELECT k.data_id 
                       FROM   table_name k
                       WHERE  k.meta_value = '1111')
```

dbfiddle [HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f1238ffdc8e28cb4897285bbfac9b72b)

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Comment: Still no luck nothing returns here is a screenshot that might help...

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want the `meta_key` to be `'meta_id'` as well as the value being `'1111'`.  I would recommend using `exists`:

```
SELECT t.meta_value 
FROM t 
WHERE meta_key = 'meta_1' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM t t2
              WHERE t2.data_id = t.data_id AND
                    t2.meta_key = 'meta_id' AND
                    t2.meta_value = '1111'
             );
```

In particular, this can make use of indexes on `(data_id, meta_key, meta_value)` and `(meta_key)`.

Comment: No luck and the query stalled here is a screnshot of the DB btw and there is over 100K of those so big table...

Comment: @rosyred33parker . . . Do you have the recommended indexes?  100k rows is not particularly big.